# Problem with apache2 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, apache2

It turns out that I am trying to see the contents of the folder but nothing comes out, I get this image.
[image]

And this is my configuration of the file that is giving me an error

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    
    <Directory /var/www/html>

        DirectoryIndex red.html
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all

    </Directory>
    
    <Directory /var/www/html/datos>

        DirectoryIndex index.html
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all

    </Directory>
    
    Alias /wiki /home/alumno/wiki
    <Directory /home/alumno/wiki>

        DirectoryIndex index.html
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

    ErrorDocument 404 /no_encontrada.html
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

What gives me an error is the following part because it worked before

```
Alias /wiki /home/alumno/wiki
    <Directory /home/alumno/wiki>

        DirectoryIndex index.html
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    
    </Directory>
```

I have restarted the service and it restarts fine for me as we can see in the following image

[image]

It should come out like the following image

[image]

the permissions of the /home/student/wiki folder is:

[image]

I just looked at the error log and it says the following

[image]

```
[Sun Jan 30 20:43:23.441530 2022] [authz_core:error] [pid 6242:tid 139632557659904] [client 127.0.0.1:57776] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/alumno/wiki
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: What are the access permissions on the directory `/home/alumno/wiki`? You may display them with the command: `ls -ld /home/alumno/wiki`

Comment: This may be caused by AppArmor blocking access to `/home`. What policies do you have in place for Apache in AppArmor? 

Comment: what is that about apparmor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you need to give it inside what this fails me.

```
Require all granted
```

I stay as follows:

```
Alias /wiki /home/alumno/wiki
    <Directory /home/alumno/wiki>

        DirectoryIndex index.html
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

This is because it worked before in version 2.2 of apache but for 2.4 you have to add that last line

[image]